# Complex OpenMP parallelization over triangles of a mesh

Tags: c++, algorithm, openmp

So I have a mesh and for each triangle I need to compute some information -- `computeInfo(triangle)`. In my sequential version I simply use an iterator for going through the whole mesh.

In order to gain some time, I am trying to parallelize this part with OpenMP. The trick is that `computeInfo(T)` accesses and modifies some triangles around triangle `T`.

My idea is the following : first compute the bounding box of the mesh. Then create an adequate 3D grid (with cells large enough so `computeInfo(T)` doesn't cause any issue) and assign each triangle to the corresponding grid cell.

Then each thread processes all the trianges in a cell which coordinates can be expressed as `(2*i, 2*j, 2*k)` : this ensures that no modification appears due to another thread. We wait for all the corresponding cells to be processed, then we processed `(2*i+1, 2*j, 2*k)`, `(2*i, 2*j+1, 2*k)`, and so on until we processed `(2*i+1, 2*j+1, 2*k+1)`.

Obviously, my parallel code is barely as fast as the sequential code (best I did was 2x faster, using 8 threads...). I think it is due to the structure I am using for storing the grid, the facet to process and so on.

Here is a simplyfied version of my code :

```
vector<set<Index> > vsGrid(nX*nY*nZ); // vector that contains each "cells"
                                      // a cell is a set of the facet index
                                      // it contains
                                      // nX, nY, nZ = size of the grid
vector<vector<set<Index> > > vvsGrid(iNbOfThreads);
// one vector for each thread

#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < iNbOfThreads; ++i)
{
    vector<set<Index> > vsGrid(nX*nY*nZ);
    vvsGrid[i] = vsGrid;
}

#pragma omp parallel
{
    const int iThrdId = omp_get_thread_num();
    // each thread process a part of the total triangles (called facet)
    for(PlaneFinderAPI::Polyhedron::Facet_iterator f = vFStart[iThrdId]; f != vFEnd[iThrdId]; ++f)
    {
        Point_3d p = barycenterOf(f);
        int X = int((p.x() - minX)/(12*meanEdgeSize));
        int Y = int((p.y() - minY)/(12*meanEdgeSize));
        int Z = int((p.z() - minZ)/(12*meanEdgeSize));

        vvsGrid[iThrdId][X+nX*Y+nX*nY*Z].insert(f->index());
    }

    #pragma omp barrier

    for(int col = iThrdId; col < nX*nY*nZ; col+=iNbOfThreads)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < iNbOfThreads; ++j)
        {
            // we merge the cells of all the threads
            vsGrid[col].insert(vvsGrid[j][col].begin(), vvsGrid[j][col].end());
        }
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < vvCellToProcess.size(); ++i)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int j = 0; j < vvCellToProcess[i].size(); ++j)
    // vvCellToProcess contains the cells to process, first vector contains all
    // the cells (2*i, 2*j, 2*k) and so on
    {
        const int iCellToProcess =  vvCellToProcess[i][j];
        for(set<Index>::iterator it = vsGrid[iCellToProcess].begin(); it != vsGrid[iCellToProcess].end(); ++it)
        {
            PlaneFinderAPI::Polyhedron::Facet_iterator f = facetMap.at(*it);
            computeInfo(f);
        }
    }
}
```

I think the major problem resides in the overuse of vector of vector of set. I don't think the memory is efficiently allocated and this is why it is slow. So what structure should I use ? Is there a more efficient way to treat my problem ?

Serial code :

```
for (PlaneFinderAPI::Polyhedron::Facet_iterator f = P.facets_begin() ; f != P.facets_end() ; ++f)
{   
    computeInfo(f);
}
```

`computeInfo` looks at vertices around f using the standard halfedge datastructure of a mesh. To avoid multiple looks at the same vertex, each vertex is associated to a boolean `visited`. This is why I can't just simply parallelize the for loop, because there will be issues in the reading/writing of the `visited` boolean.

Technical info: I am using Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2010, with an i7 960 @ 3.20GHz with 8 threads and 12GB of memory.

Comment: Allocating objects for each thread from the master thread is usually not a good idea. It can lead to false sharing for one.  Also your line `for(int col = iThrdId; col < nX*nY*nZ; col+=iNbOfThreads)` can be replaced by `#pragma omp parallel for <newline> for(int col=0; col<nX*nY*nZ; col++)`. This might be more cache friendly. But there are several other strange things you do. Could you please add the serial code you used before modifying it to work with OpenMP? That would help me understand how best to parallelize your code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I added the serial code and some details about `computeInfo`.

Comment: That's your serial code? Where's the grid? I mean your code using the cell grid but without OpenMP.

Comment: I don't need the grid for the serial code: `computeInfo` resets all the booleans modified during the call. I need the grid in the parallelization though because of these booleans: if I dumbly parallelize the loop, I will have problems with the `visited` booleans. I need to be sure that when I process simultaneously two triangles, they are far from each other so that there is no concurrency. Hence the need of a grid.

Comment: What Compile and OS are you using? What's the hardware? What function are you using to time the code?

Comment: Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2010, i7 960 @3.20Ghz with 8 threads, 12GB of memory, I'm using time.h for timing.

Comment: I mean what function are you using for timing? `clock()`?

Comment: Yes, clock() and retrieve the time in seconds by dividing by CLOCKS_PER_SEC.

Comment: okay, well it's fine with MSVC, but it's no good on Linux. I would use `omp_get_wtime()` instead but that's not going to solve your problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you benchmark your code before guessing what is slow and what is fast. Also depending on what Index is, you might have an expensive copy every time you assign and read from your vectors. You could try storing pointers of Index instead.

This line for example:

```
vvsGrid[i] = vsGrid;
```

Will cause a copy of multiple Index for each set in the vector, then a copy of each set and each Index in those set into the new vector.

Comment: I am using a timer and this part is not that time consumming. The part where I attribute a triangle to a cell is 10 times more time consumming. Index is equivalent to an int.